# Finding integer coordinates on a sphere's surface

Tags: geometry, number-theory, diophantine-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer coordinate set of points that is a member of sphere surface](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88826/integer-coordinate-set-of-points-that-is-a-member-of-sphere-surface)

Assume $C$ is a sphere with radius $r$ and center in the origin (0,0,0). How can we find the set of all points with integer coordinates that lie on the surface of $C$?

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem

Comment: @BillCook That gives points inside a circle, I require points on a surface.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76892/pythagorean-quadruples

Comment: Is the radius an integer, or the square root of an integer?

Comment: @Lubin: if it's not the square root of an integer, the answer is easy.

Comment: @Lubin Not necessarily, but it depends on what values of $r$ can generate solutions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yet that question has no answer either.

Comment: Well, it does, just not an efficient answer. There is also a suggestion that this is a Project Euler problem, and we don't do those here.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No this subject was discussed in my number theory class. I would also kindly request you stop accusing me of posting PE problems on every question I post.

Comment: "I would also kindly request you stop accusing me of posting PE problems on every question I post." Khaled, you have posted 12 questions. On 10 of them I have made no mention whatever of Project Euler. Please refrain from telling lies about my activity here.